# Failed attempt to define a record type in F#

Tags: f#

I tried to define a F# record. This does not work for me. Any idea? Below I used the interactive mode in Visual Studio.

```
{x : int};;

 Stopped due to error
 System.Exception: Operation could not be completed due to earlier error
 Unexpected symbol ':' in expression. Expected '}' or other token. at 0,3
 Unmatched '{' at 0,0
 Unexpected symbol ':' in expression. Expected '}' or other token. at 0,3
 Unmatched '{' at 0,0
 Invalid object, sequence or record expression at 0,0
 Invalid record, sequence or computation expression. Sequence expressions should be of the form 'seq { ... }' at 0,0
 Invalid object, sequence or record expression at 0,0
 Invalid record, sequence or computation expression. Sequence expressions should be of the form 'seq { ... }' at 0,0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type definition seems to be missing something. A type definition starts with the keyword `type`.

This defines a type and prints an instance of it:

```ml
type test = {x:int}  // definition
printf "%A" {x = 1}  // example use
```

See it in action here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fb0wi5

Comment: Thanks a lot. BTW, I tried to use printfn "%a" {x = 1}, with a small-case "a", and it does work any more. Any explanation on that?

Comment: The "see it in action" link is quite helpful!

Comment: printf "%A" and printf "%a" do different things, the first one just "dumps" the object, the second one expects a function with arguments as far as I recall, I never used it so you need to check the doc if you want to know exactly what it does

Comment: also my example is a bit confusing, the name of the type is "a" but it has nothing to do with %A, I'll change it to avoid this confusion